# What is the preferred method of marshalling COM interfaces across threads?

Tags: multithreading, com, marshalling

What are the pros/cons of using the GIT as opposed to CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream and CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream for marshalling COM interfaces across threads?

Are there strong reasons for preferring one method over the other, or is it more a matter of personal preference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693729(VS.85).aspx):

> If you are unmarshaling an interface
>   pointer multiple times between
>   apartments in a process, you might use
>   the IGlobalInterfaceTable interface.
>   With other techniques, you would have
>   to remarshal each time.

Besides that, I would say it's mostly a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

You need a copy of [Essential COM by Bon Box](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Essential-COM-Don-Box/dp/0201634465), when I used to work with COM, I would reach for Don's book whenever I had this sort of question.